# PCA with matrix of multiple ChIP datasets

Tags: r, bioinformatics, pca

i cultured cells in different conditions and did ChIP-Seq with a specific DNA-Damage-Response-Protein. Now i want to correlate my datasets with multiple other ChIP-Seq and do a PCA to see 'potentially' different clustering.

My first idea was to create a matrix intersecting my genomic regions with the bam files of the other ChIP-Seq data and use DESeq to normalize the intersections to get counts:

treatment 1

| Chr | Start | End | H3K9me3 | H3K4me1 | H3K16ac | γH2AX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 10025 | 10525 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| chr1 | 13252 | 13752 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| chr1 | 16019 | 16519 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 0 |
| chr1 | 96376 | 96876 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| chr1 | 115440 | 115940 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| chr1 | 235393 | 235893 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 0 |

treatment 2

| Chr | Start | End | H3K9me3 | H3K4me1 | H3K16ac | γH2AX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 10025 | 10525 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 5 |
| chr1 | 13252 | 13752 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 7 |
| chr1 | 16019 | 16519 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 8 |
| chr1 | 96376 | 96876 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| chr1 | 115440 | 115940 | 6 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| chr1 | 235393 | 235893 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 6 |

I should end up with multiple of these matrices to use them for a PCA..

Has anyone experience with this approach or maybe knows a manual/workflow i could work out?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I predict that regardless of normalization this will cluster strongly by histone mark rather than by celltype or treatment -- given that you use quantitative information such as read counts. Despite it is all ChIP-seq the technical variation between ChIPs (antibody, efficiency of pulldown, other sorts of variation) will probably dominate such a clustering approach -- again, on the quantitative scale. I think you need something more sophisticated here. If you want to learn chromatin states and predict with it I would look into something like chromHMM.